# LinkageError in websphere

Tags: java, jaxb, websphere, classloader

Help me pls with exception in WebSphere 9. I try to deploy only one war file of application with only one shared libraries.

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding method "javax/xml/bind/JAXBIntrospector.getElementName(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;" during creation of class "com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/JAXBContextImpl$3": loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@aaa95b96"  of class  "com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/JAXBContextImpl$3" and loader "com/ibm/oti/vm/BootstrapClassLoader@fd6f4560" класса "javax/xml/bind/JAXBIntrospector" have different types for the method signature
```

All config of websphere is default except:
1) Class loader order = classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last) in Enterprise Applications > name_of_war > Manage Modules > ru.bpc.cg.core.war
2) Shared libraries with enabled "Use an isolated class loader for this shared library" option.

Shared libraries contain:

```
classmate-1.0.0.jar  
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar 
jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar 
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar 
neethi-3.1.0.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar 
xalan-2.7.2.jar 
xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar 
xml-apis-1.4.01.jar 
xmlschema-core-2.2.2.jar
```

I found the QName.java and JAXBIntrospector.java in several jars in the project

[image]

[image]

Also I scan the mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose but cant find any with javax.xml

I think the eliminate the rt.jar with JAXBIntrospector.class can help me, but dont know because it is in JDK.

Comment: Is there a reason you need JAXB and JAXP in your shared library at all? Simply picking up the versions in the server/JDK will avoid the possibility of conflicts. Also, I'm not sure I understand using both an isolated shared library AND a "parent last" class loader - those are both ways of doing largely the same thing (using your own jars in preference to those in the server).

Comment: @Jarid Thank you for response. Do you mean to delete jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar and jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar from shared library?

Comment: @Jarid Would you tell which of dependencies Do I need to update in pom.xml ?

Comment: @Vadim, you should be able to use <scope>provided</scope> so that you can build your WAR, but then not package those JARs in your WAR (or shared library).